# Rsyslog server - conditionally forward logs

Tags: logging, rsyslog, kafka, centralized-logging

The idea is to receive the logs on the Rsyslog server and then send them to a specific Kafka server depending on the log contents.

For example,
Logs are being received on a single port, 514
Forwarding received logs to Kafka topic #1 and lines containing "[warning]" to Kafka topic #2

Is anything like this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module(load="omkafka")

*.* action(type="omkafka" topic="topic#1" 
    broker="10.120.169.149:9092"
    confParam=["compression.codec=snappy", "queue.buffering.max.messages=400000"])

if ($msg contains "[warning]") then {
    action(type="omkafka" topic="topic#2" 
    broker="10.120.169.149:9092"
    confParam=["compression.codec=snappy", "queue.buffering.max.messages=400000"])
}
```